# unable to get response from a click span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html structure

```
<div class='container'>

    <div class='comment-row-id-1'> <span class='user'> job </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>
    <div class='comment-row-id-2'> <span class='user'> smith </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>
    <div class='comment-row-id-3'> <span class='user'> jane </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>

</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when a user clicks on any of the span with class 'icon-trash' I wan't that to trigger onclick response.

I can handle which span was clicked, but now I am stuck at the click itself, as it does not I can not get the alert message in this example

```
jQuery(".icon-trash").click(function(){
    alert('hi')
})
```

Comment: it's because  `<span class='icon-trash'>` have nothing to display and hense not working

Comment: @AlivetoDie it is a trash symbol, so it can only be empty. I use it to delete the row

Comment: Its working https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6354/

Comment: i am unable to see any trash icon there in your code

Comment: You really needed to make the fact that the `<span>` elements aren't actually empty a little clearer to stop the obvious, red herring answers.

Comment: Instead of using a span, you should use a ```<button>``` element.  Spans aren't meant to be clickable elements and do not inherently receive focus, meaning that anyone using a keyboard would not ever be able to activate the delete action, without you writing additional JS to recreate the expected functionality of a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Why it's not working?***

For any element `click` will work only when it will occupied some physical space on browser after rendered. If element have no-conent then no space is occupied and hens `click` will not work.

So check below:-

1.if `<span class='icon-trash'>` showing trash icon on your browser then only alert will work.

2.You can provide some height/width through `CSS` so that `click` will work anyhow(with or without any content).

***Working Example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".icon-trash").click(function(){
    alert('hi');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='comment-row-id-1'> <span class='user'> job </span> <span class='icon-trash'> (Click me for trash)</span> </div>
    <div class='comment-row-id-2'> <span class='user'> smith </span> <span class='icon-trash'> (Click me for trash)</span> </div>
    <div class='comment-row-id-3'> <span class='user'> jane </span> <span class='icon-trash'> (Click me for trash)</span> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`.icon-trash` should contain something, or be block/inline-block element

```js
jQuery('.icon-trash').click(function(e){
    alert('hi')
})
```

```css
.icon-trash {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 6px;
   height: 6px;
   background: #ccc;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class='container'>

    <div class='comment-row-id-1'> <span class='user'> job </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>
    <div class='comment-row-id-2'> <span class='user'> smith </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>
    <div class='comment-row-id-3'> <span class='user'> jane </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `span` elements are empty, and therefore they probably wouldn't show in the browser to be easily clickable. I would add some CSS to make it visible. For example:

```
span.icon-trash {
    display: block
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black; 3or just anything to make it visible
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
<span class='icon-trash'> </span>
```

your span is blank that's why you are not able to click on that. Pass some value in it like:

```
<span class='icon-trash'>Hello</span>
```

and try again.

Comment: I didn't DV. But the span can't contain, it's an icon

Answer (score 2):

```
   <style>
.icon-trash {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 28px;
   height: 28px;
   background: #dfdfdf;
cursor:pointer;

}
</style>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div class='container'>

        <div class='comment-row-id-1'> <span class='user'> job </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>
        <div class='comment-row-id-2'> <span class='user'> smith </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>
        <div class='comment-row-id-3'> <span class='user'> jane </span> <span class='icon-trash'> </span> </div>

    </div
```

>
 AND

```
<script>
JQuery(function($){
$('.icon-trash').click(function(e){
    alert('hi')
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why there is an empty span used. And use . User in js file

Comment: @AlivetoDie it is a trash symbol, so it can only be empty. I use it to delete the row

Comment: $('. Container').on("keypress", function(e){
    //instead of using the span class use the div class
});

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you should consider:

**First**: Elements are loaded into DOM from up to end, one by one.
   So when you want to bind `click()` on an element, you should wait till that element is loaded into the DOM. Put `click()` in `document.ready()` for example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".icon-trash").click(function(){
        alert('hi')
    })
})
```

**Second**: Since elements load from up to down like a waterfall; if you don't want to wait till the document is ready, you should put `click()` binding function **after** the elements, not before:

```
<span class='icon-trash'> </span>


jQuery(".icon-trash").click(function(){
    alert('hi')
})
```

**Main Idea:** Be sure of that when your `click()` function works. If it works **when there are no** `icon-trash` elements in the DOM **yet**; you get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Please check now,

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".icon-trash").click(function(){
    alert('hi')
})
});
```

```css
.icon-trash img{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='container'>

    <div class='comment-row-id-1'> <span class='user'> job </span> <span class='icon-trash'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Editing//delete1600.png" width=15 height=15 /></span> </div>
    <div class='comment-row-id-2'> <span class='user'> smith </span> <span class='icon-trash'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Editing//delete1600.png" width=15 height=15 /></span> </div>
    <div class='comment-row-id-3'> <span class='user'> jane </span> <span class='icon-trash'><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Editing//delete1600.png" width=15 height=15 /></span> </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it. Use some text instead of space and use jquery code like used here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery(".icon-trash").click(function(){
  alert('hi');
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class='container'>

  <div class='comment-row-id-1'> <span class='user'> job </span> <span class='icon-trash'>text</span> </div>
  <div class='comment-row-id-2'> <span class='user'> smith </span>
 <span class='icon-trash'>text</span> </div>
  <div class='comment-row-id-3'> <span class='user'> jane </span> <span class='icon-trash'>text</span> </div>

 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helped.